# How to get actions that happened in google chrome?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, get, tabs, action

I want to get the actions that the user made an respond to them.
For example, if a user opened a new tab, I want to get that action.
If a user clicked on “save”, I want to be able to get that action and use it.
Is there a way to do so?

I tried using c# and .net but couldn’t get the wanted goal

Comment: I highly doubt you'll manage this in C#. The best chance you would have is in JavaScript, but even then, I'm not sure it's possible.  Maybe if you could explain your scenario it might help. כל טוב

Comment: Sure thing.I want to create an app or a chrome extension that responds to the user tab. For example, if a user opened a new tab - do this. If the user has closed a tab - do that. Of course these are just examples, I’m speaking about all kinds of actions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you're looking to write a Chrome extension, then you'll need to do it in HTML, CSS and (most importantly for you) JavaScript. You can't do that in C#. See this [link](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/extensions-101/) for more details.